# Repeat a callback on Button Hold down

Tags: java, android, android-camera, ontouchlistener

I implemented a Camera.PreviewCallback in my android app to grab frames from the textureview and it works fine. i would like to know to to keep repeating this callback when a button is pressed down.

My code is below:

```
 This is the code for the Camera.PreviewCallback:

    Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
    YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),size.width, size.height,  null);            
      image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90, out);
      byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
      Bitmap images = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
      rev = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
      rev.add(images);

   }
   };
```

This is the code to handle Button press down:

```
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // End
        break;
     }
    return false;
    }
  });
```

Again how do i make the callback repeat when the button is pressed down.Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? The obvious solution would be to post a `Runnable` or use a `Timer`. But don't forget to check if the `Button` is still pressed.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller please can you post an example for either the runnable or the timer. thanks am a newbie

Comment: @DonnieIbiyemi you can search for examples on stackvoerflow itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439252/how-to-pause-handler-postdelayed-timer-on-android/17439429#17439429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need a way to check if the `Button` is still pressed. For that purpose define a new boolean field called `buttonPressed`:

```
private boolean buttonPressed = false;
```

Next we define the `Runnable` we want to run as long as the `Button` is pressed:

```
private final Runnable buttonPressedRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Check if the Button is pressed
        if(buttonPressed) {
            // Insert whatever you want to do while the Button is pressed here
            ...

            // Repost the Runnable with an appropriate delay
            button.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }
};
```

Finally in your `OnTouchListener` you need to set `buttonPressed` to `true` in `ACTION_DOWN` and again to `false` in `ACTION_UP`. You also need to post the `buttonPressedRunnable` once, as long as the `Button` is pressed it will repost itself.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
                buttonPressed = true;
                button.post(buttonPressedRunnable);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                buttonPressed = false;
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```